# Knit to pdf doesn't work when using Kable

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I'm using rmarkdown in rstudio and want to knit to pdf. This works well, except for when I use kable. I'm using the following yaml and it used to work in the past, but now I had to reinstall R, Rstudio and MacTex and now it doesn't work anymore.

````
---
title: "example"
output:
  pdf_document:
    df_print: kable
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r}
cars
```
````

The error message I get is:

> output file: example.knit.md
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Environment kable-table undefined.
>
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile example.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Study-1.log for more info.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: If you reinstalled R, did you also reinstall all your packages, e.g. rmarkdown, kabelExtra, ...?

Comment: I reinstalled most of them, but I may still be missing a few. I have rmarkdown, kabelExtra, and knitr, for example, but I'm not 100% sure which ones I need.

Comment: Can you upload your complete RMD file (e.g. to github or elsewhere)?

Comment: I'll upload a basic version here:

---
title: "example"
output:
  pdf_document:
    df_print: kable
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(base)
library(broom)
library(pander)
library(knitr)
```


```{r cars, echo=FALSE}
cars
```

Comment: Without the     df_print: kable in the yaml it does work, but then the output is rather ugly. It used to work for me with that part in the yaml before I had to reinstall all my software

Comment: I think it´s a problem with MacTex, did you install `tinytex`?

Comment: Yeah I did. I just deinstalled MacTex and only run it on tinytex now, but get the same problem still.

Comment: This is what is shown right before the error message:

/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS example.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output example.tex --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' --include-in-header

Comment: /var/folders/hm/yr9n94y53_93y2px54xtff9w0000gn/T//Rtmpay2zFK/rmarkdown-strb1a310618ff4.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug of **rmarkdown** (against higher versions of Pandoc), which [I just fixed on Github](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/13a5fbbd48307e3ed1f98bf52ee586f0ded127c3). Please try:

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it does actually. May it have been solved by clearing the cache?

Comment: If the code chunk that generates the table is cached, yes, please clean the cache.